# User Forms & Finding a File

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, email, form

I'm trying to work on a way to allow users to pull down a customized PDF document - my plan is below, but happy to approach from a different angle if it would work better. Really no idea if this is possible or how to approach it.

1. Have user complete a form (on the SharePoint) that asks them for a
   unique identifier (eg ABC1234, DEF5678) and their e-mail
2. SharePoint site contains a folder with all of the files, each
   labeled with the unique identifiers (eg ABC1234, DEF5678)
3. SharePoint e-mails the e-mail address entered with a copy of the
   file matching the unique identifier

Thanks!

Comment: Are your email recipients inside your organisation or can they be external users? If they are only internal then you can use workflow on the list and send an email to the users with a dynamic link pointing to the document.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use InfoPath form to customize the relevant form.

Then create a customize workflow in SharePoint Designer with the "send an email" action.

In the action, you can select the relevant email column as receiver and type the relevant document url in the email body.

More detailed steps you can refer to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/605f5455-b93b-43ac-92ba-590f76e5bac4/user-forms-finding-a-file?forum=sharepointgeneral) post.